# Matlab: programmatically reset (all) font sizes

Tags: matlab

How can I reset the setting below using commandline in Matlab, i.e. switch to 'use system font'?

[image]

Background: I want to reset all font settings at startup

This will reset the code and editor font personal values, but not the remaining fonts (credits go [here](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/508616-how-to-change-the-matlab-desktop-code-font-size-and-desktop-font-size-programmatically)):

```
s = settings;
clearTemporaryValue(s.matlab.fonts.codefont.Size);
clearPersonalValue(s.matlab.fonts.codefont.Size);
```